# gulp-notify: [Error running Gulp] Error: Invalid UTF-8

Tags: gulp, utf-8, gulp-sass, node-modules

У меня такая проблема: всё шло нормально, занимался другим проектом. Теперь при запуске Gulp выдаёт вот такую ошибку:

> gulp-notify: [Error running Gulp] app\sass\main.sass
>   Internal Error: Invalid UTF-8

Прошерстил весь sass, переустанавливал папку node-modules, ставил gulp-sass-unicode — не помогло, все стили, что были написаны до этого — нормально применяются, новые же нет. Если что — WebStorm последней версии, всё свежее.

Comment: на какой строчке ошибка ?

Comment: Это всё в консоли выдаёт, плагин gulp-notify

Comment: добавь пожалуйста ответ, отметь свой ответ как правильный и вопрос не будет болтаться без ответа.

Comment: Я вроде так и сделал, но почему-то в комментарий отправился) Исправил

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была всего лишь в одной строчке импорта: @import ../../bourbon/bourbon Обновил бурбон — всё заработало